# inhibit sharing default arg b/w successive calls

Tags: python

[Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) -

> **Important warning:** The default value is evaluated only once 
>   ...
>   If you don’t want the default to be
>   shared between subsequent calls, you
>   can write the  function like this
>   instead:

```
def f(a, L=None):
    if L is None:
        L = []
    L.append(a)
    return L
```

I still was expecting:

```
print f(1)    # [1]
print f(2)    # [1,2]
print f(3)    # [1,2,3]
```

I reason:

The default value (`L=None`) was executed for `f(1)` which helped L point to a new empty list in the fn body. However on successive calls, `L=None` was not executed; so L still points to the list which already has 1 in it now, and subsequent calls are simply appending more elements to it thereby sharing `L`.

Where am I thinking incorrectly?

---

**UPDATE**

```
def f(a, L=[]):
    L.append(a)
    return L
```

Does L here point to an empty list created in heap or stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`L` is the name of an argument, but it is *also* a local variable. Rebinding it rebinds the local variable, but does not change the default argument.

**UPDATE EDIT:**

Python doesn't have "heap" and "stack" in the same manner as C; all it has are objects, and references to those objects. Your function call returns a reference to the same list that was created as the default value for the `L` argument of the `f` function, and any operation that mutates it will mutate the value of the default argument.

Answer (score 0):

`The default value is evaluated only once`

means that if you do `def foo(a, b=len([1,2,3]))` b will be set to 3 and it will not make any function call to `len` if you call foo.

The `=` operator assigns an object to a name. It doesn't change the previous object.

Comment: This does not answer why doing `b = 4` in the function doesn't make it 4 on subsequent calls.

Comment: @Ignacio because `=` assigns an object to a name... doesn't change the previous object

Answer (score 0):

If you run the functions below, it will help you to see how it works.

```
def f(a, L=[]):
    print("id default: ", id(L))
    L.append(a)
    print("id used: ", id(L)
    return L
```

Notice 1 object address, we are using only the default list object and we are changing it.

```
def f(a, L=[]):
    print("id default: ", id(L))
    if L == []:
        L = []
    L.append(a)
    print("id used: ", id(L))      
    return L
```

Notice 2 different object addresses, when you assign L=[] again in the function, you are using a different list object and not the default list object, and that is why the default list object doesn't change.

```
def f(a, L=None):
    print("id default", id(L))
    if L is None:
        L = []
    L.append(a) 
    print("id used: ", id(L))      
    return L
```

This function is basically the same as the one above it, same idea, but it uses a None object instead of an empty list object.